# How does ScrollView paging works?

Tags: react-native

Docs says When `pagingEnabled` is set to true, the scroll view stops on multiples of the scroll view's size when scrolling. This can be used for horizontal pagination.

I am trying to implement a carousel with say 15 items. I want to display only 5 items at a time. Every time the user scrolls, I want to scroll to the next 5 items

I am trying to figure out how the page size determined? in case of the above example, I want to set the page size to 5

What are the mandatory properties to set to achieve pagination?

Comment: There is specific reason that you want to use *ScrollView* instead of *Flatlist* in this case ? (because easily handleable pagination in Flatlist)

Comment: What properties of Flat list should i try to enable pagination?

Comment: You are be able to set **horizontal = true** and **initialNumToRender = 5** also **maxToRenderPerBatch = 5** in Flatlist in order to loading numbers data that will load per batch. If this approach was helped you that is awesome but if not you can try use temp state variable that each time user scroll inside Flatlist, it load 5 data in itself (by main data variable), you can do this by defining a function for **onEndReached** and setting **onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}**. I hope it's be helpful.